# How do I get couchdb attachment name

Tags: python, json, flask, couchdb

How do I get the name of a couchdb attachment if I only know the document name.
Do I have to filter the return document json and extract the attachment name,
so I can then append it to the end of the url /db/doc/aboutme.jpg

```
requests.get('http://localhost:5984/test2/2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either get your document with the attachments using the [attachments](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/views.html) query parameter.

Also, you can do as you described. You fetch the document. Then, you get your attachment by using the attachment name in the document.